# Visual Studio Community - disabled target platform "iOS"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have just installed Visual Studio Community Edition and as I try to create new xamarin project, I noticed one of the target platforms, "iOS" is disabled.

What should I do to see it enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the second attempt at installing Visual Studio fixed everything ... I can't imagine that I didn't have the iOS checkbox checked on first attempt ... #strange

[image]